# Returning count after name if more than one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having difficulty finding the answer for this in my searching. This is a sample table:

```
1 | Bob Smith | 
2 | Mary Jones |
3 | Paul Bunyon |
4 | Bob Smith |
5 | Bob Smith |
6 | Mary Jones |
7 | Tim Gunn |
```

I'd like to select a distinct amount of names BUT, I need the count of number of times that name is in the records displayed after returned results. So returned results should look like this:

```
Bob Smith (3)
Mary Jone (2)
Paul Bunyon
Tim Gunn
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group By` + `Count(*)` , you need to cast the `int` to `varchar`:

```
SELECT NameCount = Name + CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN ''
                          ELSE ' (' + CAST(Count(*) as varchar(10)) + ')' END
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY Name
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c870/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: +1 for being first, although I really don't think I saw your answer on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want the number to be in parentheses *conditionally* when it is greater than 1:

```
select (case when count(*) = 1 then Name
             else concat(Name, ' (', Count(*), ')')
        end)
from t
group by Name;
```

SQL Server 2012 supports the ANSI standard `concat()` function.  And, it take numeric arguments so we don't have to explicitly cast numbers to strings to concatenate them to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "group by".

select name, count(*) from table 
Group by name

Answer (score 0):

While many answers here tell you how to do it all in SQL, I would argue that you should simply return your raw data from your query:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Count(*) AS NameCount
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY Name
```

Then in your presentation layer you can worry about conditionally showing the `NameCount` in brackets when it is more than 1.

If your presentation layer is SQL, please disregard my suggestion :)